# turn disabled attribute to true or false switchery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this nice iOS checkbox plugin [Switchery iOS checkbox](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/). By default, the checkbox is disabled. Now, I want to enable the switchery checkbox if user click the button that has a class of "btn_modify" and disabled it back if user click the button that has a class of "btn_cancel". Below is my code reference.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="js-switch" checked />
<button class="btn_modify">Modify</button>
<button class="btn_cancel">Cancel</button>
```

and activate the switchery

```
//switchery
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
elems.forEach(function(html) {
  var switchery = new Switchery(html, { size: 'small', disabled: true, disabledOpacity: 1.0 });
});
```

and my attempt

```
$(".btn_modify").click(function(){
    $(".js-switch").attr("disabled", false);
});

$(".btn_cancel").click(function(){
    $(".js-switch").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

but sadly not working, any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? Did you include the jQuery Library?

Comment: I used the latest library jquery 2.x.x and yes I did include it and no problem rendering the switchery plugin

Comment: The documentation is right there on the page you linked to - keep a reference to the object, and call `.disable()` and `.enable()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-dynamic-state');
var switchery = new Switchery(elem);

document.querySelector('.js-dynamic-disable').addEventListener('click', function() {
  switchery.disable();
});

document.querySelector('.js-dynamic-enable').addEventListener('click', function() {
  switchery.enable();
});
```

In your case it will be

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
var switchery = new Switchery(elem);

document.querySelector('.btn_cancel').addEventListener('click', function() {
  switchery.disable();
});

document.querySelector('.btn_modify').addEventListener('click', function() {
  switchery.enable();
});
```

2nd Option

**CSS**

```
.disabled{
 opacity: 0.5;
 pointer-events: none;    
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".btn_modify").on("click",function(){
        $(".switchery").removeClass("disabled");
    });

$(".btn_cancel").on("click",function(){
    $(".switchery").addClass("disabled");
});
```

**[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/VHZY8/39/)**

Reference http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/

Comment: I look on it yet cant find a way to merge it with my current development.

Comment: 0.o i thought it was pretty obvious

Comment: Thanks for css option. Its easier to use this option for pre-built themes which initializes everything behind the scenes.

Comment: it keep creating me new checkbox , im using the master version see question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395449/jquery-switchery-checkbox-disable-created-new-checkbox-on-page

Answer (score -1):

disabled = false will still register as disabled. the only way to have it enabled is to remove the disabled attribute completely, something like:

```
$(".js-switch").removeAttr('disabled');
```