# Jquery Switchery checkbox disable created new checkbox on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, switchery

i struggle to disable the Switchery checkbox
but it creates me another Switchery checkbox on page .
i first define the checkbox which is working great:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2">
        Additional Options
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="foo1"
                       name="foo1" class="js-switch"/>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now after the page loaded, i dynamically want to disable the checkbox so I do :

```
var foo1=  document.getElementById('foo1')
var switchery = new Switchery(foo1);
switchery.disable();
```

it disable the checkbox BUT it creates me new checkbox near the one i defined already
i don't understand why
[image]

Comment: can you create working demo code?

Comment: it is to complex GUI app , i can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a template and it had this in their JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".js-switch")[0]) {
        var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
        elems.forEach(function (html) {
            var switchery = new Switchery(html, {
                color: '#26B99A'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This runs when the page loads and may explain why you are seeing 2 switchery objects. You may have something initializing it in a JS script and then doing it again on the page itself.

I had a similar issue trying to enable/disable switchery objects after they were created so I set up a global array of switchery objects and added functions to control their state like this:

```js
var switchery_objs = [];

function enableSwitchery(id) {
    switchery_objs[id].enable();
}

function disableSwitchery(id) {
    switchery_objs[id].disable();
}

function toggleSwitchery(id) {
    switchery_objs[id].setPosition(true);
    switchery_objs[id].handleOnchange(true);
}

function setSwitchery(id, checked) {
    if((checked && !switchery_objs[id].isChecked()) || (!checked && switchery_objs[id].isChecked())) {
        switchery_objs[id].setPosition(true);
        switchery_objs[id].handleOnchange(true);
    }
}

if (window.Switchery && $(".js-switch")[0]) {
    var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
    elems.forEach(function (html) {
        switchery_objs[html.getAttribute('id')] = new Switchery(html, {
            color: '#26B99A'
        });
    });
}
```

With this, you can just call `disableSwitchery("foo1");` to mark it as disabled.